# Android listview load images only when the list items are shown

Tags: android, listview

My android application has to show thumbnails of the audio file album art for each and every song. The mobile i'm testing on has about 2000 songs, so, I need to optimize the performance. There is a lot of lag if I use adapter's getview to load thumbnails.

So, to make it `asynchronous` I've added `thread` to load images, but it turns out 2000 threads are created to load all 2000 thumbnails.

Is there a way to optimize this? like lazy loading or live scrolling in android?

**Update:** Also, I'd like to get rid of the image thumb nails from the memory when scrolling as the number of images can cause OutOfMemory error.

Thanks.

Comment: @adcom i'm new to android, could you please eloborate?

Comment: Zeus refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview , hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

This is lib u can use for lazy loading : [Lib](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

1. Will optimize ur thumbnail performance.
2. Scroll listview smoothly
3. u can run this lib in android and watch the performance.

Comment: @Zeus yes this lib is for this task only